# How to disable auto-completion in Safari

Tags: safari, history

I hate to use Private Navigation so I disabled history (locked the History.plist file) but when I enter words in my search, auto completion sometimes show somethings I'd rather not show to my friends / familly (ie. searching for "poker" and seeing "pornhub" appear.
Do you know how to disable this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Prefs/Search - disable everything except search engine suggestions [which are 'live' not historical]

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped :)